# Semi-Circle Marker or Semi-Circle Drawing in ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, data-visualization

How can I use a semi-circle for my points using ggplot2? If that is not an option, how can I draw a filled semi-circle and plot it at my desired coordinates?

Ideally, I would like the shapes used here: https://twitter.com/SethWalder/status/1442270885142880261, but I am assuming that is even more complex and perhaps harder to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unicode for a similar character to the shape you want

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,y = Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(shape = "\u2BCA",size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me. Are there any other additional packages required?